# Trouble with creating new dataset from a model

Tags: r, rows, models, poisson

I am trying to create a plot similar to the plot on the link: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/nbreg.htm .

For the plot of the predicted results with the confidence intervals. The code i am using is listed below, which for everything i have been able to find is identical to the code listed on the site quoted above.

```
 summary(modelpoisson<-glmer(respiratory_morbidity~mdata2$prevpercent+mdata2$weightclass+mdata2$interpretation+(1|feedlot),family="poisson",offset=log(mdata2$starting_head)),data=mdata2)

    newdata2p <- data.frame(
      prevpercent = rep(seq(from = min(mdata2$prevpercent), to = max(mdata2$prevpercent), length.out = 20), 5),
      interpretation  = factor(rep(1:5, each = 20), levels = 1:5, labels =
                      levels(mdata2$interpretation )))

    newdata2p <- cbind(newdata2p, predict(modelpoisson, newdata2p,type="link", se.fit=TRUE))
    newdata2p <- within(newdata2, {
      respiratory_morbidity <- exp(fit)
      LL <- exp(fit - 1.96 * se.fit)
      UL <- exp(fit + 1.96 * se.fit)
    })
```

However when I run this code I get the following error when I try to create the data frame newdata2p

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

The following errors show up:

```
  newdata2p <- data.frame(
    + prevpercent = rep(seq(from = min(mdata2$prevpercent), to = max(mdata2$prevpercent), length.out = 20), 5),
    + interpretation  = factor(rep(1:5, each = 20), levels = 1:5, labels =
    + levels(mdata2$interpretation )))
    > View(newdata2p)
    > newdata2p <- cbind(newdata2p, predict(modelpoisson, newdata2p,type="link", se.fit=TRUE))
    Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = integer(0)) : 
      replacement has 0 rows, data has 100
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In predict.merMod(modelpoisson, newdata2p, type = "link", se.fit = TRUE) :
      unused arguments ignored
    2: 'newdata' had 100 rows but variables found have 134 rows
```

Thank you!

Comment: what are dimensions of `newdata2p` and `predict(..)`, can you separately save result of `predict(..)`? and make sure that part is working

Comment: > dim(newdata2p)
[1] 100   2

Comment: if i cut out the predict(...) part of the code it give the same error as above.   I don't understand the difference between what is going on in this code and the example code on the website listed above...

Comment: I believe, your predict is not working, resulting in different length of rows, it seems newdata2p has 100 rows and predict may have resulted in 134? what is the output of predict alone? If data is not that big can you do, `dput(mdata2`) and paste here?

Comment: I don't know.  I can't make that part work... suggestions?

Comment: `dput(mdata2)` would allow us to help you better

Comment: data is pretty long to paste

Comment: well than what about `dim(predict(modelpoisson, newdata2p,type="link", se.fit=TRUE))`

Comment: 1 1 11 7826 354 13 19 12/18/2012 774 5 No Growth 0 0.000000 0.036723164 0.053672316 700
2 2 11 7828 546 31 39 12/18/2012 774 5 M.haem 1 20.000000 0.056776557 0.071428571 700
3 3 11 7859 235 25 27 1/13/2013 742 6 M.spp 1 16.666667 0.106382979 0.114893617 700
4 4 11 7859 235 25 27 1/13/2013 742 6 P.mult 6 100.000000 0.106382979 0.114893617 700
5 5 11 7863 358 18 20 1/13/2013 742 4 H.som 1 25.000000 0.050279330 0.055865922 700

Comment: didn't format well.  I tried to paste an example

Comment: newdata2p  does not have weightclass

Comment: dim(predict(modelpoisson, newdata2p,type="link", se.fit=TRUE))
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 100
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In predict.merMod(modelpoisson, newdata2p, type = "link", se.fit = TRUE) :
  unused arguments ignored
2: 'newdata' had 100 rows but variables found have 134 rows 
>

Comment: you can always edit the question and format it there, so it would help me and also other to better understand the question

Comment: didn't occur to me that weight class could be the problem.  I removed it from the newdata2p code because having that variable kept me from creating that dataset

Comment: The predict on new data wont work if the variables in the initial model are not included

Comment: I suggest you to edit the question with head(mdata2) and see all the variables in new and old dataset

Comment: newdata2p <- data.frame(
+   prevpercent = rep(seq(from = min(mdata2$prevpercent), to = max(mdata2$prevpercent), length.out = 20), 5),
+   interpretation  = factor(rep(1:5, each = 20), levels = 1:5, labels =
+                   levels(mdata2$interpretation )),
+   weightclass = factor(rep(1:6,each=20),levels=1:6,labels=levels(mdata2$weightclass)))
Error in factor(rep(1:6, each = 20), levels = 1:6, labels = levels(mdata2$weightclass)) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 0 should be 1 or 6
>

Comment: @Ananta   The variables are different in the two sets, but I think that should be the case.  in newdata2p I am trying to create a set of predicted #'s based not the model and the range of the variable prevpercent

Comment: you are adding 120 `rep(1:6, each=20)` to a dataframe that is supposed to have 100, are you trying to write `rep(1:5)`

Comment: rep(1:5) give the same result.  There are 6 levels to this variable, so I need 6.  But you have a good point about the 120 vs 100.   I think the problem is that the third variable adds an extra dimension.  I have tried multiple ways to include the variable and have failed.    Do I need to make enough rows that I can make a common # for all 3 variables with different # of levels?

Comment: Yes, Use expand.grid instead of data.frame

Comment: > newdata2p <- expand.grid(
+   prevpercent = rep(seq(from = min(mdata2$prevpercent), to = max(mdata2$prevpercent), length.out = 20), 5),
+   interpretation  = factor(rep(1:5, each = 20), levels = 1:5, labels =
+                              levels(mdata2$interpretation )),
+   weightclass = factor(rep(1:6,each=20),levels=1:6,labels=levels(mdata2$weightclass)))
Error in factor(rep(1:6, each = 20), levels = 1:6, labels = levels(mdata2$weightclass)) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 0 should be 1 or 6

Comment: Try 
> newdata2p <- expand.grid(prevpercent = seq(from = min(mdata2$prevpercent), 
      to = max(mdata2$prevpercent), length.out = 20), 
      interpretation =  levels(mdata2$interpretation ),
      weightclass = levels(mdata2$weightclass))

Comment: head(newdata2p)
[1] prevpercent    interpretation
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: Well i don't know what is going on. As for example, expand.grid(prevpercent = seq(1,10, length.out = 20),  
                     interpretation = 1:5, 
                     weightclass = 1:6), works. So look at each variable in your original dataset in turn; make sure interpretation and weightclass are factors

Comment: interpreation is a factor.  weight class is not.  it is num

Comment: ok, so then levels(weightclass) is meaningless. Try newdata2p <- expand.grid(prevpercent = seq(from = min(mdata2$prevpercent), to = max(mdata2$prevpercent), length.out = 20), interpretation = levels(mdata2$interpretation ), weightclass = mdata2$weightclass)

Comment: BTW if weightclass is not a factor it will be treated as a continuous variable in your original lmer call. Is this what you intend/

Comment: @user20650  The code posted 2 above will create the data frame.  However it leaves out creating a predicted value to plot.  How can I produce the predicted output from the model and store it in this data frame to plot? I did not intend to have weight class as a continuous variable, but after converting it to a factor as weight.class it didn't change any of my problems

Comment: newdata2p$pred <- predict(modelpoisson, newdat=newdata2p) should work. This will return cases rather than rates. I dont have lme4 on this laptop so can;t check. GL